# ui-select doesn't run tagging mod and Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tags, ui-select

I want to run a `ui-select` that use for keyword tag. At first load, when I enter a new tag everythings is ok and but remove all tag a enter tag again error me:

> Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

[Demo](http://codepen.io/essvision/pen/pymrmQ?editors=1011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init `$scope.availableOptions` in your controller.

By:

```
app.controller('builder', function($scope) {

  /**
   * default fields
   */

  $scope.availableOptions = []; // <- add this line.

  $scope.newItemNo = 1;
  $scope.finalFields = [];
  $scope.field = {
    'index': $scope.newItemNo,
    title: 'choice1',
    type: 'string',
    length: 20,
    htmlType: 'text',
    validations: [],
    searchable: true,
    fillable: false,
    primary: false,
    show: true,
    select: [],
    radio: [],
    checkbox: 1
  };
});
```

Fixed [demo](http://codepen.io/smallyin/pen/KzLXmY?editors=1011).

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to choice list. Is it possible?

Comment: Do not need the dropdown when input?

Comment: I don't need to dropdown